# Tricky : 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is a tricky error that you could fall into with dictionary using Python:

```
dict = {'a':5,'c':5}
#Typing some codes
```

And at some point of the program, you decide to create an empty dictionary:

```
new_dic = dict()
```

You get this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Could you tell me if it is a bug in Python or simply we have to be careful when using built-in functions, not to assign their names previously for some variables?

Comment: There is no way this was a bug. Could you pase the first line of your code?

Comment: Also, there is no way there could be an `int` being called. The error would say `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`.

Comment: You can bind any value to any non-keyword name (with some exceptions like `None = ...`). Python name-resolving mechanism do not disallow you to do it, therefore you are allowed to do it. It's a language design decision, not a bug. _we're all consenting adults here_.

Comment: I love how almost every answer illustrates the problem exactly as you did in your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you've run into is called "shadowing". You've created an object in some namespace (either the global namespace of your module, or the local namespace of a function) that has the same name as a the builtin `dict` type. This prevents you from accessing the builtin `dict` in the usual way.

You *can* still get to it, with a bit more effort. The `builtins` (or `__builtin__` in Python 2) module holds all the built in objects that are normally accessible directly. So, to make your empty dictionary, you could do the following:

```
import builtins

dict = whatever

newdic = builtins.dict()
```

But... It's probably just a better idea to avoid using the name `dict` for your own objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your first line is overwriting what **dict** is. Try this instead.

```
dictA = {'a':5,'c':5}
new_dic = dict()
```

and you problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, functions (and everything else) are first-class objects. So Python is interpreting your call like this:

```
dict() -> call value of variable "dict" as a function
```

In your case, because the value stored in `dict` is not code, you get an exception.

Here's a quick example of how you might use this way of calling functions.

```
>>> a = lambda x: x + 2
>>> a
<function <lambda> at 0x10116b230>
>>> a(3)
5
>>> a(7)
9
```

Here I stored a lambda (anonymous func) in `a`, which I can then call as a function later.

You can also assign a function to a variable, then call it using the variable name.

```
def a(x):
    return x + 2

b = a
b(3)    # returns 5
```

You can also use this pattern with nested functions to create closures.

In any case, you will be better off if you just avoid using variable names that are also keywords or builtins.

https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of shadowing. The assignment shadows the built-in `dict` type:

```
>>> type(dict)
<type 'type'>
>>> dict = {'a':5,'c':5}
>>> type(dict)
<type 'dict'>
```

And as the error describes, `dict` istances are not callable.

The same thing often happens with the `sum` built-in.